# Putting a rectangular backdrop behind an iframe

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a page with an embedded YouTube video at the top, below the header, navbar, and title. It's in a centered column 620px wide that scales when the window is small (the video scales with it). I need to put some sort of rectangle behind it which stretches up to the navbar, out to either side of the page, and about 5-10px below the video. (Building an awkward showcase, essentially.) It should be able to hold an image, and I'd most prefer a CSS-only solution. I do have to work within the confines of Joomla/Bootstrap.

I'm sure it's possible, but I've been trying for hours and nothing's worked. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe show us what you tried? A fiddle could help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3gy/382/ It's gotten a little crazy.